# how to make a porfolio carousil like this in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor, custom-wordpress-pages

[image]
i have this portfolio carousel , i tried some plugins but its not custmazble at all , what is the best way to acheive this same result as you see in the picture.

thanks in advance community

i tried plugins like portfolio gallery carousel but its nt customizable , and the user interface is not cool at all , i want to acheive this same result , i have diffrent images in diffrent portfolios , and i want them also to be shown all